# Predefined type 'System.Object' is not defined or imported [dnxcore50]

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-code

Today, my project full of these errors. Same with "string", "int", etc. I am running the latest VS Code on Yosemite.  Uninstalled and reinstalled DNVM.  Deleted all packages from .dnx.  I can run my program, but this is really bothering me.

#### 3rd party edit

Using visual studio code 1.73.1 on [windows-10](/questions/tagged/windows-10)  with [.net-7.0](/questions/tagged/.net-7.0) the error is this

```
Type "System.Object" is not defined or imported csharp(CS0518)
```

Steps to reproduce

1. Open a folder with vs code
2. Open a terminal and run `dotnet new console --use-program-main`
3. Open `Program.cs` and see the result below

##### Screen of vs-code error

[image: VS-Code_Error]

##### 3rd party VS Code version details

> Version: 1.73.1 (system setup)
> Commit: 6261075646f055b99068d3688932416f2346dd3b
> Date: 2022-11-09T04:27:29.066Z
> Electron: 19.0.17
> Chromium: 102.0.5005.167        Node.js: 16.14.2
> V8: 10.2.154.15-electron.0
>
> OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.19042
> Sandboxed: No

In my version

Comment: I had add to add a dependency to "System.Runtime": "4.0.20-beta-22231" to fix this condition, which seems to have appeared in the newer version 4.0.20-beta-23008.

Comment: Please post some version numbers and more about your project setup. There has been lots of instability in the last few weeks of nightly builds from ASP.NET

Comment: I have the same problem.  I used yo aspnet-generator to create a console app and I get the same error on my main class.  Your same fix fixed my problem too.

Comment: The question [75323687](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75323687) may be related